# What is the probability of rolling 2 7's before 6 even numbers on successive rolls of a pair of fair dice?

Tags: probability

Would this equal Pr( rolling 2 7's)/Pr(rolling 2 7's or rolling 6 even numbers)? Or could I approach the problem as follows:

1- (Pr(rolling 6 even numbers)+ Pr( rolling 5 even numbers, 7 and an even number)) ?

Comment: What exactly is "rolling 6 even numbers"? Three times rolling two even numbers? Or six times a sum that is even?

Comment: A sum that is even.

Comment: To add clarification to the question: the experiment consists of an **unending** sequence of **independent** trials. In each trial, two dice are rolled. The result of each trial is the sum of the numbers on each dice. i.e. the result of each trial could an even number or, a $7$ or, an odd number *other than* $7$. find the probability that **at least** two $7's$ are rolled, before  6 even numbers are rolled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the assumption that your question means that you roll a pair of dice several times and stop when you have rolled either six even numbers or two sevens during the sequence, then neither of your answers are correct.

What you need to do is look at the probability of rolling a seven before an even number: this is $\dfrac{\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{4}$.

You can then work out the probabilities of getting to the position of $a$ sevens and $b$ even numbers without having previously stopped.  You have

- $\Pr(0,0)=1$,
- $\Pr(0,b)=\frac{3}{4}\Pr(0,b-1)$ for $1\le b \le 6$,
- $\Pr(a,0)=\frac{1}{4}\Pr(a-1,0)$ for $1\le a \le 2$,
- $\Pr(1,b)=\frac{3}{4}\Pr(1,b-1)+\frac{1}{4}\Pr(0,b)$ for $1\le b \le 5$,
- $\Pr(1,6)=\frac{3}{4}\Pr(1,5)$,  and
- $\Pr(2,b)=\frac{1}{4}\Pr(1,b)$ for $1\le b \le 5$.

The answer is $$\sum_{b=0}^5 \Pr(2,b)= \dfrac{4547}{8192} \approx 0.555.$$

Comment: I am trying to work it out and I am finding it rather laborious, is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: I know this is an outdated post, but how did you calculate that last step? did you just substitute the  value with the previous equations as I just cant work it out? apologize if it is supposed to be obvious.

Comment: @Fred: just set up a grid with $a \in \{0,1,2\}, b \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and then fill in the numbers.  Brian M. Scott's later calculation confirms it

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a slightly different way to look at it.

Odd rolls other than seven are meaningless and can be ignored. By the seventh meaningful roll you must have either two sevens or six even numbers. Thus, you get two sevens before you get six even numbers if and only if you get at least two sevens in the first seven rolls.

On each meaningful roll the probability of getting a seven is $$\frac{\frac16}{\frac16+\frac12} = \frac14,$$ so the probability of getting at most one seven in seven meaningful rolls is $$\binom70\left(\frac34\right)^7 + \binom71\left(\frac14\right)\left(\frac34\right)^6 = \frac{3^7+7\cdot 3^6}{4^7} = \frac{10\cdot 3^6}{4^7} = \frac{3645}{8192}.$$

The probability of getting at least two sevens in seven meaningful rolls is therefore $$1 - \frac{3645}{8192} = \frac{4547}{8192}.$$

Comment: There is a typo in the last row, should be 1 minus, btw, your ans is very very clear! Thx

Comment: let $E$ be the event that 2 sevens are rolled before 6 evens are rolled    and     let $O$ be the event that an odd number except 7 is rolled at some point

Comment: according to the above answer, $P(E) = P(E|O^c)$,
which implies that the events $E$ and $O$ are independent(which is obvious because, occurrence or non-occurrence of $O$ does not give any *new* information about $E$)

Comment: Why exactly the odd rolls are meaningless? I mean why they can be ignored in the calculation?

Comment: @AnkitSeth: See *abhishek*’s comments above yours: they give a brief explanation.